# WPF StackPanel Items should repeat themselves

Tags: c#, wpf, loops, stackpanel, items

I am adding buttons to the Stack-panel on run time in C# WPF. What i want is the when i am scrolling through the Stack panel items once i reach the last time i want it to show the first item after the last one so it kinds of keeps repeating the list.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" CanContentScroll="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                              Name="SVMenu" Margin="-2,45,2,39" Grid.RowSpan="3">

                        <StackPanel x:Name="stackpanel_Menu1">

                        </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
```

and this is the Code for creating the buttons.

```
 DataTable dt = db.VIEW_MENUS();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            Button Btn = new Button();
            Label LB = new Label();
            Btn.Content = dr[1].ToString();
            Object obj = dr["MENUIMAGE"];
            if (obj != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    ImageBrush BtnBrush = new ImageBrush();
                    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream((byte[])obj))
                    {
                        BtnBrush.ImageSource = BitmapFrame.Create(stream,
                                          BitmapCreateOptions.None,
                                          BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
                    }
                    //// Use the brush to paint the button's background.
                    Btn.Background = BtnBrush;

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }
            Btn.Tag = dr["MENUID"];
            Btn.Click += btn1_Click;
            Style style = this.FindResource("CircleButton") as Style;
            Btn.Style = style;
            Btn.Width = 85;
            Btn.Height = 85;
            Btn.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            Btn.Margin = new Thickness(0,2,0,0.1);
            //an(Btn);
            LB.Foreground = Brushes.White;
            LB.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            LB.Content = dr["MENUTITLE"];
            LB.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            StackPanel stackpanel_Menu = new StackPanel();
            stackpanel_Menu.Children.Add(Btn);
            stackpanel_Menu.Children.Add(LB);
            stackpanel_Menu1.Children.Add(stackpanel_Menu);
```

so it adds 15 buttons to the Stackpanel and i can see them vertically. When i can scrolling to the last 15th button i want it to show me the first button again and keep scrolling down, rather then ending the scroll.

Comment: You may want to create a specialized layout Panel. See [How to: Create a Custom Panel Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-create-a-custom-panel-element).

Comment: "show me the first button again" : That is by definition not a StackPanel. Shop around for other panels.

Answer (score 0):

This is not available out of the box in WPF

Either find a 3rd party control or write your own implementation.